# Canada Tourist vs. Business visa

Tags: canada, tourist-visas

I am attending a conference in Canada in December. I have a tourist visitor visa from a previous visit in April 2018. That visa says: Category: V-1 Visitor, Multiple Entry and is valid until 2024.

On the CAN gov website here: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp

For the question, "What do you plan to do in Canada?", when I choose:

(a) Visit Canada, family or friends (this was my reason for my previous visit)

It says: You need a visitor visa to travel to Canada.

And, when I choose:

(b) Attend a business meeting, conference or trade show (my reason for the upcoming visit)

It says: You’re considered a business visitor and you need a visitor visa to travel to Canada.

It appears that both visas are the same, but the wording is slightly different and they have two separate entries for these two reasons of visit. How can I check if I need to apply for a different visa or if I can reuse my existing visa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the V-1 visitor visa for a business visit, until its expiry date. Canada's temporary resident visas (aka visitor visas) are good for tourism, business and transit.

From the [Immigration Canada FAQ](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=455&top=16):

> *I got a multiple-entry temporary resident visa to visit a relative in Canada last year. Can I use it to travel to Canada on a business trip?*
>
> Yes, as long as it has not expired. Make sure you have documents that support your business visit to Canada. See [Business visitors: Checklists](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/business/checklists.html) for more information.